# R Convert all values of multiple dataframe rows to one vector in order

Tags: r, dataframe, vector

I have a dataframe in R with observations that I would like to convert to one vector. All the rows have the same columns (with some NAs present in certain columns). I know that I can extract them all individually, but I am wondering what the most succinct way to extract all of the values (in order) is, to then convert them to one vector. I would like to read out all the values of row 1 (column-1, column-2... column-n), followed by row 2, followed by row 3...etc.

Example with sample data:

Row 1:     1, 2,  3, 4, 5, NA, 1

Row 2:     2, 3,  4, 5, 6, 8,  NA

Row 3:     7, 9, 2,  3, 5, 12, 14

Desired Vector:   1, 2,  3, 4, 5, NA, 1, 2, 3,  4, 5, 6, 8,  NA, 7, 9, 2,  3, 5, 12, 14

To then remove NAs and receive:
1, 2,  3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3,  4, 5, 6, 8, 7, 9, 2,  3, 5, 12, 14

Given that I have numerous rows and columns, what is the most succinct way to do this, rather than individually extracting each row/column's values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also do this:

```
df |>
  #turn the rows into columns
  t() |>
  #combine the colums into one vector
  Reduce(f = c) |>
  #drop na
  Filter(f = Negate(is.na))
# [1]  1  2  3  4  5  1  2  3  4  5  6  8  7  9  2  3  5 12 14
```

The `df` is from [Mohamed Desouky](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73029515/21932715).

You can also use `apply` with the `MARGIN=2` argument and drop the `NA` first. Then combine the list into a sigle vector:

```
df |> apply(2, na.omit) |> Reduce(f = c)
# x  y  z  x  y  z  x  y  z  x  y  z  x  y  z  y  z  x  z 
# 1  2  7  2  3  9  3  4  2  4  5  3  5  6  5  8 12  1 14
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
as.vector(na.omit(as.vector(t(as.matrix(df)))))
```

- output

```
1  2  3  4  5  1  2  3  4  5  6  8  7  9  2  3  5 12 14
```

- data

```
df <- structure(list(X1 = c(1, 2, 7), X2 = c(2, 3, 9), X3 = c(3, 4, 
2), X4 = c(4, 5, 3), X5 = c(5, 6, 5), X6 = c(NA, 8, 12), X7 = c(1, 
NA, 14)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("x", "y", "z"))
```